# What is the difference between Al Idraj wal Wad' (الإدراج و الوضع)?

Tags: uloom-al-hadith

Al Idraj is a saying not of the Prophet's (May God's blessings and peace be upon Him), and is sometimes on the part of the narrator, either to clarify a word or to make a saying of the Prophet (May God's blessings and peace be upon Him) more complete.  A Wad' means fabrication.  So, what is the difference between Al Idraj wal Wad' (الإدراج و الوضع)?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is simple:

In case of Al Idraj, the narrator does **not** claim that the part the explains or clarifies the hadith from the prophet words -peace be upon him-. In many hadiths the distinguish is made explicit, for example after narrating the hadith the person says and `I say` and then explain or clarify the meaning.

However, in the fabricated hadith the narrator completely make the entire hadith from his/her mind and **claim** it to be from the prophet sayings -peace be upon him- .